# Flutter package Slidable width

Tags: flutter, dart

im using `flutter_slidable: ^1.2.0` package
how do i adjust the width of the `SlidableAction` ?
and is it able to edit the radius? with BorderRadius.circular maybe

one more if i press the delete button i want to run dismiss animation function how ?

[image]

here is the full code

```
 for (var i = 0; i < c.noteList.length; i++)
                  Slidable(
                    key: ValueKey(
                      c.noteList[i]['id'],
                    ),
                    startActionPane: ActionPane(
                      motion: StretchMotion(),
                      dismissible: DismissiblePane(
                        onDismissed: () {
                          handleDeleteSet(
                            c.noteList[i]['id'],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                      children: [
                        SlidableAction(
                          onPressed: (context) {},
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                          icon: Icons.delete,
                          label: 'Delete',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: NoteTile(
                      index: i + 1,
                      item: c.noteList[i],
                      deleteItem: (id) {
                        handleDeleteSet(id);
                      },
                      onSaveData: () {
                        saveData();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For editing the width of the slidable area, you should use the `extentRatio` parameter, which accepts a double value above 0 and below 1:

```
ActionPane(
    extentRatio: 0.7,
    motion: const ScrollMotion(),
    children: []
),
```

For the radius, just use a `Container` and `decoration` parameter:

```
ActionPane(
    extentRatio: 0.7,
    motion: const ScrollMotion(),
    children: [
      Container(
        height: 180,
        width: width(context, 60),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for this exactly
• https://github.com/letsar/flutter_slidable/issues/432